Unable to resolve dependies
Here i have attached the screen shotenter image description here
below is my app.build gradle
All the projects i have is getting same issue only
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
    ext {
        appVersionCode = 39
        appVersionName = '3.79'
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2')
        classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.20'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.1'
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:oss-licenses-plugin:0.10.5'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.45"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url  "https://dl.bintray.com/steveliles/maven"
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

can any on help me on this
i need to know why the dependencies are not getting resolved

Because you are using repositories, which simply do not exist anymore; jcenter() for certain.

jcenter() i have removed and tried then also getting same error

Remove the jcenter for sure. It looks like Jitpack has the one you showcased in the screenshot, so can follow its instruction to recheck your code base (as you did not put much here so we could not investigate future).
https://jitpack.io/#medyo/android-about-page/1.3
